# Jars needed for JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have downloaded *JasperReports* jars (jasperreports-5.6.0-project.zip from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/)) and toke all the jars in the dist folder. These are the files I added to my project:

```
jasperreports-5.6.0.jar
jasperreports-applet-5.6.0.jar
jasperreports-fonts-5.6.0.jar
jasperreports-javaflow-5.6.0.jar
```

But when I try my code I always get this error:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory`

**UPDATE 1**

I solved that error and I have a lot of more missing jars. Please tell me all the additional jars needed to use *JasperReports*.

Comment: You can find all dependencies in root *pom.xml*.

Comment: @AlexK But I am not using Maven...

Comment: I've just recently downloaded it and see no `dist` folder ? Idk where to get these other JARs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, as I said I added the jars in the dist folder of the downloaded zip (as showed in the question) to my project and to resolve all the problems I had, I added the next jars from the lib folder to my project:

`JasperReports 5.6.0 - ...`

```
...poi-3.7-20101029.jar
...commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
...commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
...commons-digester-2.1.jar
...commons-javaflow-20060411.jar
...commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
...groovy-all-2.0.1.jar
...iText-2.1.7.js2.jar
...jcommon-1.0.15.jar
...jfreechart-1.0.12.jar
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: how did you acquire this `dist` folder? I downloaded iReport from sourceforge and did not see a `dist` folder in my .zip

Comment: @mmcrae the file of the link in my question is the JasperReport Library (jasperreports-6.1.1-project.zip [new version]). Press the big green button that says download and you will find all those files there.

Comment: I didn't find these libraries at all in your provided link intead i only found the three , i had o manually download it and fell into other errors , can you provide a link to download these libraries instead of just listing them like this?

Answer (score 1):

these are gradle dependencies i needed to make Jasper Report work in Spring Boot:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports
compile group: 'net.sf.jasperreports', name: 'jasperreports', version: '5.0.1'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging
compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.1.2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext
compile group: 'com.lowagie', name: 'itext', version: '2.1.7'
```

Hope it helps someone.